# My internal data isn't update in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I developing app with Visual Studio and I have a problem.
Well I go showing the file distribution:

```
Services
├── CloudDataStore.cs
├── FolioDataService.cs
├── IDataStore.cs
├── IPictureStore.cs
├── ISTDataService.cs
├── MockDataStore.cs
├── PictureService.cs
└── STDataService.cs
Views
├── AboutPage.xaml
├── AboutPage.xaml.cs
├── ItemDetailPage.xaml
├── ItemDetailPage.xaml.cs
├── ItemsPage.xaml
├── ItemsPage.xaml.cs
├── LoginPage.xaml
├── LoginPage.xaml.cs
├── NewItemPage.xaml
└── NewItemPage.xaml.cs
ViewModels/
├── AboutViewModel.cs
├── BaseViewModel.cs
├── ItemDetailViewModel.cs
├── ItemsViewModel.cs
└── LoginViewModel.cs
Models
├── Folio.cs
├── Item.cs
├── PicItem.cs
├── ST.cs
└── STData.cs
```

Well, my `ItemsPage` is a summary of my `ItemsPageDetail`, I explain this...
my `ItemsPage` looks like this

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout x:Name="General" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="5">
                    <Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="250.25, 0.25, 50, 50 "/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="ST:" /><Label Text = "{Binding ST_string}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                    <Label Text="Folio:" /><Label Text = "{Binding Folio_string}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Well, I explain my interaction with app, the idea is that you enter the `Views/ItemsDetailPage`, choose an `ST` and a `Folio`, where in each `SelectedIndexChanged` method I update with my `ViewModel.DataStore` that is created in BaseViewModel in this way `public IPictureStore <PicItem> DataStore => DependencyService.Get <IPictureStore <PicItem >> ()`, the problem is that I perform my update inside as I put at the end of the `.xaml` files, but when I return to the `Views/ItemsPage` I can see the photos correctly (`FileName` in `Views/ItemsPage`) But I am not able to update my information correctly in the database, I feel that I have errors of concept in how I use my service or maybe I have no association with it, although in `ViewModels/BaseViewModel` are declared, when the photograph is inserted it is made of this form:

```
Await picService.AddItemAsync (Item);
Items.Add (Item);
```

**UPDATE**

I think it's because of the way I call my service, I call `viewModel.DataStore.Update(foo)`, however, when inserting an image they use a service directly, but this service is delivered from higher classes, but, that of `Await picService` in `ViewModels`, but I do not quite understand how to work with this, although I made this change and it still looks the same, `viewModel.DataStore.UpdateItemAsync (picker.Items [selectItem], "" this.notes.Text, viewModel.Item )` => `Await p.UpdateItemAsync (picker.Items [selectItem], "" this.notes.Text, viewModel.Item)`, where `p` is a `PictureService` created in `ItemDetailPage.xaml.cs`

I can't see the real data in my main view, and I don't know.

If you need more code, I can show this.

Thank and very thanks!

Comment: "I am not able to update my information correctly in the database" - why do you think this is the problem?  Are you getting errors or exceptions?  How are you testing this?  Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: I update my ask

Comment: @Jason something???